# New python interactive window cell does not indicate if it is still running

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, interactive, indicator

lately there was an update to the VSCode python interactive window. There are a few things that bother me since.. and maybe there is a setting to solve this?

Biggest problem: The collapsed cell does not indicate the status of execution anymore. Is it still running or finished?
[image: Collapsed cell. No indicator.]

So I have to expand the cell to see the current status.. checkmark at the bottom.
[image]

There is an option to expand the cell by default, but that would show ALL the code in the cell which is way to confusing for all day workflow.

I searched for an option to expand the cell but only show the first line of the code or something. But I can't find anything. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!